# How to load json file data to existing couchbase bucket through command line or manually?

Tags: json, couchbase, couchbase-view, couchbase-bucket

As i have created a data file in JSON format and I want to know how to load that JSON file to existing Couchbase Server bucket through command line or manually?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [cbimport command line tool](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/tools/cbimport-json.html) that ships with Couchbase Server that you can use to import JSON (or CSV) data.

Here's an example that imports a JSON "lines" file into localhost and generates a UUID key

```
$ cbimport json -c couchbase://localhost -u myusername -p mypassword \
 -b mybucket -d file:///data/myjson.json -f lines -g #UUID#
```

Answer (score 1):

To add it manually, you can simply copy and paste the contents into the UI.

Go to Buckets -> click "Documents" next to the bucket you want -> click "Add Document" on the top right.

First, enter whatever key you want. Next, paste the JSON contents.